# MySQL find if other row(s) exist in the same table with the same value

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm relatively new to MySQL and need a little guidance.  I have a table called events looking like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| event_id | promoter_id | venue_id | event_date | attendance |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    0     |      5      |     1    | 2013-05-30 |     400    |
|    1     |      2      |     6    | 2013-06-09 |     104    |
|    2     |      9      |     1    | 2013-05-30 |     300    |
|    3     |      1      |     3    | 2013-06-09 |     205    |
|    4     |      3      |     2    | 2013-06-01 |     175    |
|    5     |      5      |     2    | 2013-06-01 |     295    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am looking for the attendance for the events of promoters that occur at the same venue and date as other events.  In this example all I want to get back from the query is the attendance of all events for promoter 5 that shared the same venue and date.

```
--------------
| attendance |
--------------
|     400    |
|     295    |
--------------
```

This query makes logical sense to me but obviously I am missing something as it generates a syntax error....

```
SELECT t1.attendance FROM events t1 WHERE promoter_id=5 
    JOIN (SELECT event_id, venue_id, event_date, attendance FROM events 
        WHERE promoter_id!=5) t2 
    ON t1.event_id=t2.event_id 
    WHERE t1.venue_id=t2.venue_id 
        AND t1.event_date=t2.event_date;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I haven't gotten any where near what I need on my own research.  I would prefer to do this without creating a view as I would have to delete the view after I get the results (as the table grows I feel this could be a performance hit especially as I intend to run this query for every promoter).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT attendance FROM events NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   venue_id, event_date
  FROM     events
  GROUP BY venue_id, event_date
  HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
) t WHERE promoter_id = 5
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/401be0/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.attendance 
FROM   events t1 
WHERE  promoter_id = 5 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT event_id
                   FROM events 
                   WHERE promoter_id!=5
                         AND venue_id = t1.venue_id=venue_id 
                         AND event_date = t1.event_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're including the 400 and 295 because other promoters had events at the same venue on the same day. If that's the case, try this:

```
SELECT attendance
FROM events
WHERE promoter_id = 5 AND (venue_id, event_date) IN (
  SELECT venue_id, event_date
  FROM events
  WHERE promoter_id <> 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are plenty of answers, but to address your syntax error:
You are performing a WHERE clause before your JOIN.
The where clause is also ambiguous as it points to promoter_id in both table t1 and t2.

Try this:

```
/* Select sum of attendance columns */
SELECT (t1.attendance + t2.attendance) attendance
FROM events t1
/*Specify Join immediately after FROM clause*/
JOIN events t2
/* declare all join specific conditionals before initiating WHERE clause */
ON t1.venue_id = t2.venue_id
AND t1.event_date = t2.event_date
AND t2.promoter_id != 5
WHERE t1.promoter_id = 5;
```

The above query will give you:

```
--------------
| attendance |
--------------
|     700    |
|     470    |
--------------
```

To have it broken down, you can break apart the sum of attendance fields.

```
SELECT t1.attendance, t2.attendance, t1.venue_id
FROM events t1
/*Specify Join immediately after FROM clause*/
JOIN events t2
/* declare all join specific conditionals before initiating WHERE clause */
ON t1.venue_id = t2.venue_id
AND t1.event_date = t2.event_date
AND t2.promoter_id != 5
WHERE t1.promoter_id = 5;
```

The above query will give you:

```
---------------------------------------
| attendance |  attendance | venue_id |
---------------------------------------
|     400    |       300   | 1        |
|     295    |       175   | 2        |
---------------------------------------
```